# Correctly populate table with data from parse

Tags: swift, parse-platform, swift2

So this isn't a question about actually populating a table with data because I already have that working properly.

I have a page that retrieves a list of nearby users - it grabs their name, distance away and profile image. The problem is that because some profile images are bigger than others the correct profile image isn't always put alongside the corresponding name and other data.

```
let profileImgFile = location["profilePicture"]

profileImgFile!.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { (data: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

     if error != nil {

           print("\(__FUNCTION__) - Error: (error!.localizedDescription)")

     } else {

          let image = UIImage(data: data!)

          self.userImages.append(image!)

          self.userTable.reloadData()

     }

}
```

This is how I'm retrieving the images, they're added to an array so that the table can be populated here:

```
cell.nameLabel.text = "\(userData[indexPath.row])"
cell.profileImage.image = userImages[indexPath.row]
cell.distanceLabel.text = ("\(userDistance[indexPath.row])")
```

So, I wondered if there was any way of retrieving the images one after the other. So that the next image doesn't begin downloading until the first one has finished.

If not is there any other way of fixing this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try setting your data async with promises.

- [Promises in Swift](https://medium.com/@robringham/promises-in-swift-66f377c3e403)
- [PromiseKit](http://promisekit.org/)

And there's a lot of other resources out there.